# Why is holder.textView accessible directly witout creating an object of the class?

Tags: java, android

I have this adapter class:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends PagedListAdapter<Item, ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {
    private Context context;

    ItemAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new ItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Item item = getItem(position);
        holder.textView.setText(item.name); //Why?!?!
    }

    class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;

        ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_text_view);
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the `onBindViewHolder()` method, why can I access directly `holder.textView` since `ItemViewHolder` is not static? How is this possible to access a field without creating on object of the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you're not creating an instance (what you called "object") doesn't mean you aren't using one. In fact, you *did* create an instance of ItemViewHolder, right in your `onCreateViewHolder()` method:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    return new ItemViewHolder(view); //right here
}
```

The instance returned by `onCreateViewHolder()` is what's passed to `onBindViewHolder()` (`onCreateViewHolder()` and `onBindViewHolder()` are called for each item in your dataset, so there's a unique-ish instance of ItemViewHolder for each item [RecyclerViews actually recycle ViewHolders, but that's another subject]).

---

```
ItemViewHolder.textView
```

wouldn't work because that *is* an example of static access.

What you're referencing, though, is an actual instance.

---

TL;DR, `holder` is an instance. It's not a static reference.

Comment: I think you meant `right in your onCreateViewHolder()` not `onCreateView()`. Perfectly understood. Please edit your answer. Thanks TheWanderer!!